# TypeORM Order by Subquery

Tags: typeorm

Is there a way to order a TypeORM query by a join table's aggregated value? I've attempted this a few ways now, but I'm more or less trying to convert this query into query builder output:

```
select po.*, c.status_change_date
from posts po
left join (
    select c.post_id, min(c.status_change_date) min_change_date
    from comments c
    group by c.post_id
    ) c
on c.post_id = po.id
order by c.min_change_date
```

My query builder looks like this:

```
postRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('posts')
      .leftJoinAndSelect(
          (sqb) => {
            return sqb
              .select(
                'c.post_id, min(c.status_change_date) min_change_date'
              )
              .from(CommentsEntity, 'c')
              .groupBy('c.post_id');
          },
          'c',
          'posts.id = c.post_id'
        )
        .addSelect('c.min_change_date')
        .orderBy('c.min_change_date', 'ASC');
```

The error this is throwing at the moment is "Cannot get entity metadata for the given alias "c"". It seems like it needs to know which entity represents the subquery, but I don't know how to properly provide that detail.

Comment: I believe you should use different aliases for CommentsEntity and the leftJoinAndSelect (which is the 'c' above 'posts.id = c.post_id'). I was looking into some of the suggestions here: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2132#issuecomment-1086779830

Comment: @RoarS. thank you for the suggestion. I just tried that and got the same error.